# When to do slice vs non-slice in .data section in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I have a code which plots lines and circles.

I know what does `slice` do below.
But when do we use `slice` vs non slice way of a variable in `.data` section?

```
 var link = g.selectAll(".link")
             .data(nodes.descendants().slice(1))
             .enter().append("path")
             .attr("class", "link")
             .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.data.level;})
             .attr("d", function(d)
             {
                return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
                + "L" + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
             });

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
             .data(nodes.descendants())
             .enter().append("g")
             .attr("class", "node")
             .attr("transform", function(d)
             {
               return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
             });

var circle = node.append("circle").attr("r",30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are using `descendants()` with [`d3.hierarchy`](https://%20https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy) - notice in the console output below that `Eve` has no parent because it is the 'root' node, and that all the other nodes in the `descendants()` array do have a parent.

```js
const nodes = d3.hierarchy(data);
for (let d of nodes.descendants()) {
  let name = d.data.name;
  let depth = d.depth;
  let parentName = d.parent ? d.parent.data.name : 'no parent - no link!';
  let msg = `Name: ${name}; Depth: ${depth}; Parent: ${parentName}`;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
const data = {
  "name": "Eve",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Cain"
    },
    {
      "name": "Seth",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enos"
        },
        {
          "name": "Noam"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Abel"
    },
    {
      "name": "Awan",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Enoch"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Azura"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Then note `d` function:

```
.attr("d", function(d)
{
  return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
  + "L" + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
});
```

Which says `M`ove the the centre of the 'child' circle and draw the `L`ine to the middle of the 'parent' circle. Because your 'root' node (`Eve`) has no parent then this node should be eliminated from the link layout hence `slice(1)`. But because all the other nodes should be connected to `Eve` then this root node is not `slice`d from here:

```
var node = g.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes.descendants())
```

In order that the circle for the `Eve` node is drawn and therefore the links from the child nodes of `Eve` can connect to something.

Comment: Thanks, now I understood that I didn't actually know the slice method meaning.